# Storing my NFT image as SVG display properly on Opensea but shows a broken image on metamask

Tags: solidity, metamask, nft, frontend

To store my NFT image on-chain i use the SVG format. As long as i base64 encoded them, they worked very well on any ERC721 compliant platform. But as Base64 encoding is very costly in term of computing and storing (same SVG is 1.33x bigger in Base64 than plain svg) i experimented with storing an optimised version of my svg as string in my NFT's uri:

A dummy NFT URI is actually like that:

```
data:application/json,{"name": "TEST","description": "TEST","image":"data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='300' height='300'%3E%3Cstyle%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5B.E%7Btext-anchor:middle%7D.F%7Bdominant-baseline:middle%7D.G%7Bfill:%23fff%7D%5D%5D%3E%3C/style%3E%3Crect rx='5%25' width='300' height='300' fill='%23ed1c24'/%3E%3Crect y='50' rx='5%25' width='300' height='250' fill='%23231f20'/%3E%3Cpath d='M0 110h300v170H0z' fill='%23b7d1da'/%3E%3Ctext x='150' y='25' font-size='22' font-weight='700' class='E F G'%3ETEST Collector%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='150' y='70' class='E F G'%3ETEST%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='150' y='90' class='E F G'%3EOM%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='150' y='130' class='E F G'%3EVar1: TEST Riviera%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='150' y='155' class='E F G'%3EDate: 23/05/2023%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='150' y='180' class='E F G'%3EPlace: 24D%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='150' y='290' class='E F G'%3ECERTIFICAT %231%3C/text%3E%3C/svg%3E"}
```

As you can see, my image is properly encoded to be displayed in most common platforms. However when i inspect the "broken image" in my Metamask chrome extension's NFT tab, i can see that it's been "decoded" which seems to be the reason why it won't display properly:

```
<img class="nft-details__image" src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svgxmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'width='300'height='300'><style><![CDATA[.E{text-anchor:middle}.F{dominant-baseline:middle}.G{fill:#fff}]]></style><rectrx='5%'width='300'height='300'fill='#ed1c24'/><recty='50'rx='5%'width='300'height='250'fill='#231f20'/><pathd='M0110h300v170H0z'fill='#b7d1da'/><textx='150'y='25'font-size='22'font-weight='700'class='EFG'>TESTCollector</text><textx='150'y='70'class='EFG'>TEST</text><textx='150'y='90'class='EFG'>TEST</text><textx='150'y='130'class='EFG'>Var1:TEST</text><textx='150'y='155'class='EFG'>Date:23/05/2023</text><textx='150'y='180'class='EFG'>Place:24D</text><textx='150'y='290'class='EFG'>CERTIFICAT#1</text></svg>" >
```

Can anyone think of a strategy to make Metamask display my NFT properly? I don't feel like going back to Base64.